# Sort multidimensional array by a particular value (using asort and rasort)

Tags: php

I realize there are several other questions pertaining to this - but either they dont make sense to me, or don't work how I need.

I have an array that is easy to sort by the first value alphabetically by using `asort()` and `arsort()`. An example of my multidimensional array might be:

```
[{"Name":"Amber","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Bob","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Hans","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Jeff","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Michael","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0}]
```

With using `asort()` and `arsort()` it is sorted by `"Name"` alphabetically or reverse alphabetical. Now I need the same functionality, only based on `"dealType"`.

I have tried a few examples already posted on Stackoverflow, but I must misunderstand them because they are not working. How might I accomplish this?

**EDIT**
Jonathan gave the correct answer for alphabetical sorting, with a slight modification:

```
//the custom function to do our sort
function cmp($a,$b){
    //get which string is less or 0 if both are the same
    $cmp = strcasecmp($a->dealType, $b->dealType);
    //if the strings are the same, check name
    return $cmp;
}
//sort using a custom function
usort($obj, 'cmp');
```

and this code below for reverse alphabetical sorting:

```
//the custom function to do our sort
function cmp($a,$b){
    //get which string is less or 0 if both are the same
    $cmp = strcasecmp($b->dealType, $a->dealType);
    //if the strings are the same, check name
    return $cmp;
}
//sort using a custom function
usort($obj, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [usort](http://www.php.net/usort) which will allow you to use a custom compare function to determine which value comes first when sorting.

something like:

```
<?php
//the data you supplied. normally just an array
$data = array ( 0 => array ( 'Name' => 'Amber', 'date' => '', 'dealType' => 'deal1', 'id' => '***@***.com', 'registered' => 0, ), 1 => array ( 'Name' => 'Bob', 'date' => '', 'dealType' => 'deal5', 'id' => '***@***.com', 'registered' => 0, ), 2 => array ( 'Name' => 'Hans', 'date' => '', 'dealType' => 'deal3', 'id' => '***@***.com', 'registered' => 0, ), 3 => array ( 'Name' => 'Jeff', 'date' => '', 'dealType' => 'deal2', 'id' => '***@***.com', 'registered' => 0, ), 4 => array ( 'Name' => 'Michael', 'date' => '', 'dealType' => 'deal1', 'id' => '***@***.com', 'registered' => 0, ), );

//show what we got going into sort
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, 1).'</pre>';

function cmp($a,$b){
    //get which string is less or 0 if both are the same
    $cmp = strcasecmp($a['dealType'], $b['dealType']);
    //if the strings are the same, check name
    if($cmp == 0){
        //compare the name
        $cmp = strcasecmp($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
    }
    return $cmp;
}
//sort using a custom function
usort($data, 'cmp');

//show what we got after sort
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, 1).'</pre>';
?>
```

that will sort on `dealType` first, then `Name` second if the `dealType` is the same. If you want to sort in reverse, then you can swap the order of `$a` and `$b` in the `strcasecmp()` calls.

Edit: Chances are this data is being pulled from a database. If so then just `ORDER BY` the columns. You can do like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dealType ASC,Name ASC`

Edit2: updated the code to not use an anonymous function. also you can view the code working at [ideone](http://ideone.com/bFgXa)

Comment: It is being given to me via a .NET WCF... otherwise I would do what your edit said. Your code above is giving an error of some sort.

Comment: older versions of php (<php 5.3) don't allow anonymous functions. updated the code. Other than that, you would need to show the error.

Comment: what is the error? I have it working on two servers and ideone.

Comment: Let me see if I can find it in the log

Comment: I updated the code, took out the anonymous function and changed the data from `json_decode(data)` to an actual array. You can see it working on ideone also. If that doesn't fix it, I couldn't tell you what the problem is as `server error (500)` is a generic error. You would need to check your apache/php logs to find the error or set display_errors to on and error_reporting to something like E_ALL.

Comment: I forgot to decode the array... it comes in JSON :) I will do that and let you know how it works.

Comment: Ok, so here is what I get back after its decoded: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Name] => Amber [date] => [dealType] => B-Braun Medical, Inc. [id] => ****@bbraun.com [registered] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Name] => Bob [date] => [dealType] => B-Braun Medical, Inc. [id] => ****@bbraun.com [registered] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Name] => Hans [date] => [dealType] => B-Braun Medical, Inc. [id] => ****@bbraun.com [registered] => 0 )`. This wont work with your code... do I misunderstand what I have? This is a `var_dump()` BTW

Comment: in json_decode(), pass `true` as the second parameter to have it return an array instead of a stdClass object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10295/discussion-between-jonathan-kuhn-and-mdance)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly, you have array (say A) of arrays (say Bs) and you want to sort Bs by some value in them. If thats right, i had the same problem before and made custom function called line_sort. 
If you want, you can use it by the example:

```
$array=json_decode('[{"Name":"Amber","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Bob","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Hans","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Jeff","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0},{"Name":"Michael","date":"","dealType":"B-Braun Medical, Inc.","id":"***@***.com","registered":0}]');
$array=line_sort("dealType",$array);
```

first value is key by which you want to sort, second is array to be sorted, here is the function code (sorry its not in english):

```
function line_sort($klic,$hodnoty)
{
  if (!is_array($hodnoty))
  {
    trigger_error("Second parameter has to be multidimensional array", E_USER_WARNING );
    return;
  }
  for ($x=0;$x<count($hodnoty)-1;$x++)
  {
    for ($y=count($hodnoty)-1;$y>=$x;$y--)
    {
      $radek1=$hodnoty[$y];
      $radek2=$hodnoty[$y+1];
      if ((isset($radek1[$klic]) && isset($radek2[$klic])) && (intval($radek1[$klic]) > intval($radek2[$klic])) || (isset($radek2[$klic]) && !isset($radek1[$klic])))
      {
        $hodnoty[$y]=$radek2;
        $hodnoty[$y+1]=$radek1;
        continue;
      }
      else if((isset($radek1[$klic]) && isset($radek2[$klic])) && (intval($radek1[$klic]) == intval($radek2[$klic])))
      {
        if (strcmp($radek1[$klic],$radek2[$klic])>0)
        {
          $hodnoty[$y]=$radek2;
          $hodnoty[$y+1]=$radek1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $hodnoty;
}
```

If you want to see example of output for this function, check out this: http://test.hanzlsoft.eu/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `array_multisort()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Example:

```
<?php
$ar = array(
       array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),
       array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
      );
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
                $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
var_dump($ar);
?>
```

*Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#example-4558*

Comment: `array_multisort()` has always been a mystery to me for some reason... It would be great if you could explain how to use it and adapt your answer to the question.

Comment: `array_multisort()` isnt working... isn't sorting anything. At least how I have it set up: `array_multisort($objVZA[1], SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING);`

Comment: @mdance, `array_multisort()` *is* working as long as you can get the right incantation...